# Canvas profiler for updated chrome

Tags: google-chrome, canvas

Why has chrome removed **canvas inspection** from developer options? In case I need to trace canvas rendering for each frame, what is the tool/extension that I can use for current version of chrome(mine is 49.0.2623.87)?